# SQL Queries in VBA Macros on Open Excel Workbook - Caching Issue

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Apologies for being vague, as I'm trying my best to explain the problem I'm facing. I'm having problems with Excel macros that I've written that perform SQL queries on open Excel workbooks using a DAO recordset. These procedures tend to query a worksheet based table (on Sheet1), copy the output of the query to another sheet (Sheet2) and then another query might by performed on Sheet2 to output the final result to another sheet. This used to work perfectly when we were able to do this on a different server, but is falling down now that we've been forced to run it on a new server.

The kind of error that randomly occurs is that, for example, the first query will work and the correct output will appear on sheet 2, but when the second query is made on Sheet2, the query will not recognise that the contents of sheet 2 has been updated. It might treat it as if it still had the same data it had before the first query was performed. Having searched the web for solutions / advice on this, I've often been advised that this is a memory leakage issue, but never seen a good solution. If anyone can provide me with any tips for this issue, it will be hugely appreciated.
Here is a simple example of a query I might attempt:

```
StrQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT Col1,Col2 FROM [Temp$] WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"
Set Conn = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
Set db = Conn.OpenDatabase(ThisWorkbook.FullName, False, True, "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;")
Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset(StrQuery)
Temp2.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst2
rst2.Close
db.Close
```

Would just like to add that this seems to be a caching issue that relates to these posts:

[ADO recordset seems to cache old results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513804/ado-recordset-seems-to-cache-old-results)

[ADO Recordset Returns Old (Stale) Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418248/ado-recordset-returns-old-stale-data)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** - this is completely wrong: tested without saves and the correct data is retrieved.

Apologies for the derail...

<del>When you run a SQL query on an Excel file it queries the file as it exists *on disk* (ie. not in *memory*), so if you've not saved it after updating the content then the updated content will not be accessible to (eg) a query which queries output from a previous query.</del>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's interesting because I've been able to perform queries on Excel sheets that have been changed since being saved and the query has been applied to the updated version of the sheet without another save having been made. This is when I've been querying the same workbook in which I've written the SQL query in a VBA macro. It's only been since I've started working on a new server that I've encountered these problems. Can you think why this would be?

Comment: I will double-check my assertion about querying the on-disk copy and get back to you...

Comment: Thank you very much. Since moving to a new server, it's become temperamental. 9 times out of 10 it's fine, but there's that one time when it fails.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Tim. Really appreciate you checking that out. It's encouraging that it might still be possible that this is a legitimate approach. Sometimes there are cases where a query does not recognise the current state of a worksheet and a cached version is queried. Saving always commits the latest version of a sheet-based table, but I'd to love to be able to avoid having to save. I'm wondering if there is any approach, other than saving that ensures that the current version of a sheet is always queried.

Comment: Sorry I don't have much insight into what your sporadic issue might be.  If you can't pin it down then it might be safer to take a non-SQL approach (though certainly less convenient since it would involve more code...)

Comment: Thanks Tim. Yes. That may be what I have to revert to, which would be a real shame as I have written a lot of Excel macros at work that are SQL driven and efficient and they would require a lot of recoding.